# Cloud functions - blur an inappropriate image

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to analyze an image when uploaded, and blur it if the content is considered inappropriate.

The log `this image is inappropriate` does work fine, so the detection works. However I don't see any logs after that, so I guess the `blurImage` function does not work properly.

I'm having a hard time debugging what is wrong in this function and why I don't see any further logs.

```js
exports.controlImage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(
  async (object) => {
    const bucket = storage.bucket(object.bucket);
    const file = bucket.file(object.name);

    const fileName = object.name;
    const destBucket = admin.storage().bucket(bucket);
    const file = destBucket.file(filePath); */
    

    
  
    // Check the image content using the Cloud Vision API.
    return client.safeSearchDetection(`gs://${bucket.name}/${file.name}`)
    .then((data) => {
      const safeSearch = data[0];
      functions.logger.log('SafeSearch results on image', safeSearch);
  
      if (safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.violence === 'VERY_LIKELY' ||
          safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.violence === 'POSSIBLE' ||
          safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.adult === 'VERY_LIKELY' ||
          safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.adult === 'POSSIBLE') {
            functions.logger.log("this image is innapropriate")
            blurImage(object.name, object.bucket, object.metadata);
            return null
      }
      else functions.logger.log("this image is ok")
      return null;
    });
}
)
/**
 * Blurs the given image located in the given bucket using ImageMagick.
 */
 function blurImage(filePath, bucketName, metadata) {
  const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
  const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
  const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);

  // Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
  return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
    functions.logger.log('Temporary directory has been created', tempLocalDir);
    // Download file from bucket.
    return bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempLocalFile});
  }).then(() => {
    functions.logger.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
    // Blur the image using ImageMagick.
    return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-channel', 'RGBA', '-blur', '0x8', tempLocalFile]);
  }).then(() => {
    functions.logger.log('Blurred image created at', tempLocalFile);
    // Uploading the Blurred image.
    return bucket.upload(tempLocalFile, {
      destination: filePath,
      metadata: {metadata: metadata}, // Keeping custom metadata.
    });
  }).then(() => {
    functions.logger.log('Blurred image uploaded to Storage at', filePath);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
    return functions.logger.log('Deleted local file', filePath);
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because by doing

```
blurImage(object.name, object.bucket, object.metadata);
return null;
```

you actually don't wait that the **asynchronous** `blurImage()` function is completed before indicating to the Cloud Function platform that it can clean up the Cloud Function (via `return null;`).

In other words, you need to wait this `blurImage()` function is completed before returning `null`.

Since you use `async`, here is an adapted version of your CF (without using `then()` together with `async/await`) (untested):

```
exports.controlImage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(
    async (object) => {
        const bucket = storage.bucket(object.bucket);
        const file = bucket.file(object.name);

        const fileName = object.name;
        const destBucket = admin.storage().bucket(bucket);
        const file = destBucket.file(filePath); * /


        // Check the image content using the Cloud Vision API.
        const data = await client.safeSearchDetection(`gs://${bucket.name}/${file.name}`);

        const safeSearch = data[0];
        functions.logger.log('SafeSearch results on image', safeSearch);

        if (safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.violence === 'VERY_LIKELY' ||
            safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.violence === 'POSSIBLE' ||
            safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.adult === 'VERY_LIKELY' ||
            safeSearch.safeSearchAnnotation.adult === 'POSSIBLE') {
            functions.logger.log("this image is innapropriate")
            await blurImage(object.name, object.bucket, object.metadata);  // See the await here!!
        } else {
            functions.logger.log("this image is ok")
        }
        return null;

    });
```

Comment: Right, I forgot the await before. Unfortunately, I still don't see any logs from the `blurImage` function : `2021-03-23T17:02:29.156Z I controlImage: this image is innapropriate
2021-03-23T17:02:29.238797683Z D controlImage: Function execution took 2441 ms, finished with status: 'ok' `

Comment: And is the image blurred?

Comment: I guess your Cloud Function is inspired by the [official sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/moderate-images/functions/index.js). What if you use the updated code from the sample (which uses async/await everywhere)?

Comment: I'll try that :)

Comment: I think that it worked with the await, thanks ! However is it normal that the uploaded image is not a jpeg but a `application/octet-stream` ?

Comment: I think it depends on the content type you assign to it when uploading. (But not 100% sure, I should do some tests, but I don't have time now...)